# Is it possible to extend the inventory?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've got to travel back to town pretty often to sell my looted [items](http://www.pathofexile.com/item-data).  Will I be able to reduce these travels' frequency in the future ?  Is it possible to buy or craft additional pouches to extend the inventory ?

Comment: In the early stages of the game, I fully encourage picking up all blue items and returning to town every so often (usually at waypoints) to sell for various forms of currency. Save these up, but later on you won't be having inventory issues, as these items will mostly only sell for lower currency items (identify/teleport scrolls), and therefore less useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to make the inventory bigger, just to buy more tabs for the stash. I don't foresee any changes to this in the future.

My advice to you, since I used to be the same way, is to not pick everything up, just the things that might fetch more than a few pennies back in town. If you do pick up a gray it should probably be something that you want to upgrade with an orb.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In PoE, there is no reason to hoard anything you can find. Since there is no gold but only exchanges, most of the time it's not even worth travelling back to town to sell something. PoE forces you to change the compulsive hoarding for something more thought through. If you want to clickclickclick on everything to sell it after as gold, Torchlight 2 is much more adapted (it's a compulsive clicker's paradise).

Comment: Actually I want to sell as much as possible to obtain scrolls of wisdom and identify new interesting equipments :)

Comment: @Anto In the beginning of the game, this strategy is fine - later on you will have stacks upon stacks of wisdom scrolls, so no need to sell everything you find anymore.

Comment: Note that specific gray items may be worth more than blues. Any items with at least one red, one green, and one blue slot AND are all linked will give you a Chromatic gem, worth much more than the shards of Alteration or Augmentation.

Answer (score -1):

best answer 
spoiler you should try and get the menagerie as early as possible and always have nets on hand

catch something then talk to the dude that appears that takes the animal then say something about the menagerie then go through portal and sell your stuff

go back through portal and you will be back where you were and you need to ask about menagerie again for portal to appear.